# Assembly.Evidence in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, authenticode

I have some .net framework code to port to core.  One task is to verify the authenticode signature of a certain assembly is from a specific certificate.  In .net framework its done like this

`Publisher p = someAssembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<Publisher>();`

And then `p.Certificate` is checked

But in core `Assembly` has no property `Evidence`

Does anyone know how you go about verifying a authenticode signature on .net core? (Windows only)

Thanks